# WIX Toolset 3 | Как разрешить установку MSI только из командной строки и полностью перекрыть через UI

Tags: windowsinstaller, wix

Задача **запустить MSI только из командной строки**.
При попытке запуска через UI надо выдать соответствующее сообщение, что запуск может быть осуществлён только посредством команды.
Буду рад подсказке, не могу найти необходимую инфу.

Answer (score 0):

Есть свойство [UILevel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uilevel), которое определяет уровень UI, отображаемого при установке - от `INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE` до `INSTALLUILEVEL_FULL`. Задается аргументами `msiexec /q{n|b|r|f}`. При запуске можно проверить значение этого свойства. Если оно отличается от дефолтного, то скорее всего инсталлятор запускали из командной строки (с аргументом `/q`).

```xml
<Condition Message="You need to launch this installer from command line with parameters ...">
  <![CDATA[UILevel == 2]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: Спасибо, проверю